# ¿Cómo puedo iniciar programas al arracar automaticamente en diferentes areas de trabajo?

Tags: boot

Actualmente uso el programa Aplicaciones al inicio (Starup Applications) para arrancar mis programas de uso continuo, sin embargo, quiero abrir programas en areas de trabajo diferentes y quisiera saber como puedo hacerlo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**English translation**

How can I start programs by automatically booting into different work areas?

Currently I use the Startup Applications program to start my continuous use programs, however I want to open programs in different workspaces and I would like to know how I can do it. Cheers

---

Since you have to specify the full path in Startup Applications, the OS assumes that you are not in any specific directory.  Instead of using the executable, try using a bash script to start your application.  The bash script should cd to the correct location before running the application.